# Simple GUI in Python using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple GUI in python using tkinter. What I am trying to do is

1. Place my entry element in the center of the upper half of the GUI window
2. Place a button right next to it
3. On clicking button, open up an interface to choose a file
4. Display the file name along with its path in the entry element

   ```
   def center_window(width, height):
       # get screen width and height
       screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
       screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

       # calculate position x and y coordinates
       x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
       y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
       root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))

       def OnButtonClick(self):
           self.entryVariable.set( tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename() )
           self.entry.focus_set()
           self.entry.selection_range(0, tkinter.END)


   root = tkinter.Tk()
   center_window(400, 300)
   root.title("A simple GUI")
   root.entryVariable = tkinter.StringVar()
   root.entry = tkinter.Entry(root,textvariable=root.entryVariable)
   root.entry.grid(column=10,row=5,columnspan=20)
   B = tkinter.Button(root, text ="Choose", command=OnButtonClick(root))
   B.grid(column=30,row=5, columnspan=2)
   ```

Could anybody guide me how can I move `entry` element and `button` in the center of the upper half of the GUI window. Also, how can I make `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()` function to be invoked on clicking the button. It gets invoked as soon as the GUI window opens when I run the above code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the revised code. Basically, you need to pass a function object to the `command` argument of a `Button`, which means you can either pass a function without the trailing parenthesis (if it doesn't take any argument) or use `lambda`. In your original code, your function was executed immediately after the python interpreter reaches that line. Also, you need to call `root.mainloop` at the end of the program.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
def center_window(width, height):
    # get screen width and height
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    # calculate position x and y coordinates
    x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
    y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))

def OnButtonClick(self):
    self.entryVariable.set( tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename() )
    self.entry.focus_set()
    self.entry.selection_range(0, tkinter.END)


root = tkinter.Tk()
center_window(400, 300)
root.title("A simple GUI")
root.entryVariable = tkinter.StringVar()
frame=tkinter.Frame(root)
root.entry = tkinter.Entry(frame,textvariable=root.entryVariable)
B = tkinter.Button(frame, text ="Choose", command=lambda: OnButtonClick(root))
root.entry.grid(column=0,row=0)
B.grid(column=1,row=0)
frame.pack(pady=100)  #Change this number to move the frame up or down
root.mainloop()
```